# How to select random IDs and all transactions within those random IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, r

I need to select a representative sample of all shoppers from a huge transactional database such that all transactions by those shoppers are included in the sample.

Table:

```
UserID  TransId
1          1   
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
3          1
4          1
4          2
4          3
4          4
```

50% Sample of shoppers:

```
UserID  TransId
2          1
2          2
4          1
4          2
4          3
4          4
```

How do I write a SQL query in R? The table is in a MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to connect to SQL databases from R. My personal favorite is the `RODBC` package.

From `RODBC`, you can use the `sqlQuery()` function to pass `SQL` queries to a variety of databases, providing that they accept ODBC connections.

The following code will load the `RODBC` library, assign a connection called `con` and use that connection to select all records from a table called `MyTable`.

```
library(RODBC) ###Load library

con <- odbcConnect("POC") ###Assign database connection

sqlQuery(con, "select * from MyTable")
```

For your current problem, I would use the `tablesample` function available on SQLServer 2005 and beyond. There are a number of ways to do this, but the following joins the table via an inner join to a subquery of itself (i.e. the 50 percent sample).

The query would look something like this:

```
select distinct
  rnd.UserID, TransID
from MyTable 
  join (select UserID 
        from MyTable
        tablesample (50 percent)) rnd
    on rnd.UserID = MyTable.UserID 
 order by rnd.UserID
```

Which you can pass through `sqlQuery()` as follows:

```
sqlQuery(con, 
     "select distinct
        rnd.UserID, TransID
      from MyTable 
        join (select UserID 
            from MyTable
            tablesample (50 percent)) rnd
        on rnd.UserID = MyTable.UserID 
      order by rnd.UserID")
```

This should get you a 50 percent pseudo-random sample of Userids from `MyTable` with every unique `TransID` for a given `UserID`.