# Extract unique ids and then get all rows matching a random sample of those unique ids

Tags: sql-server, random

I'd like to do something similar to [How to select random IDs and all transactions within those random IDs in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695255/how-to-select-random-ids-and-all-transactions-within-those-random-ids-in-sql) but all within Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
My very large master table has travel records by individual and month:

```
FileDate     PersID     Location...
200001          1           A
200001          2           B
200001          3           A
200002          1           C
200002          2           C
200003          1           D
200004          1           A
```

There are about 260 million rows in the master table and about 4.2 million unique PersIDs.

To get started, I'm trying to just return the random sample of unique PersIDs. I've tried a number of things, the simplest of which is

```
SELECT distinct PersID FROM mastertbl
TABLESAMPLE (1 percent);
```

I've also tried wrapping the "SELECT distinct PersID" query as a subquery within another query and applying TABLESAMPLE in the outer query.

All of my attempts return about 1.7 million rows, which is 40% of the unique PersIDs not 1%. This makes me suspicious that my sampling method is sampling the master table and then applying the distinct criteria, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry 2012. Not sure where the 11 came from.

Answer (score 0):

Some pertinent quotes from [the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx):

> TABLESAMPLE cannot be applied to derived tables

So the subquery thing is a no-go.

And:

> If you really want a random sample of individual rows, modify your query to filter out rows randomly, instead of using TABLESAMPLE. For example, the following query uses the NEWID function to return approximately one percent of the rows of the Sales.SalesOrderDetail table:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
> WHERE 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float)
>             / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
> ```

It looks like you'll need to use the technique demonstrated in the second quote, something like:

```
select * from (
    select distinct id from mastertbl
) x
where 0.01 >= cast(checksum(newid(), id) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / cast(0x7fffffff AS int)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that technique still gives me too many results.